# Route http traffic from Azure to AWS via another AWS account or on-Prem

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, apache-kafka, databricks

I am looking for an answer regarding my following network related problem scenario:

I have the following resources:

- Azure Databricks cluster - in Azure Account e.g. let's call it: Azure 1.
- Apache Kafka Cluster - in AWS Account e.g. let's call it: AWS 1
- Another AWS Account e.g. let's call it: AWS 2

Now, I need to get the streaming data loaded from my Kafka Topics inside AWS 1 into my Azure Databricks (Azure 1) using the Kafka connector provided by Azure Databricks.

The problem is that as per the existing network policy setup in account AWS 1, the Kafka cluster (broker) is not accessible from the Azure 1 account, but from either AWS 2 (via private-link, already in place) or from company's on-Prem network.

So my question is how can I somehow route my Azure Databricks' offered Kafka connector (in Azure 1) traffic to either AWS 2 or On-Prem to reach the Kafka broker in AWS 1?

What options do I have?
My preferred approach would be to follow: Azure1->AWS2->AWS1 route
otherwise, Azure1->on-Prem-AWS1

What additional service do I need in Azure1 and/or AWS2 and/or on-Prem to route the traffic to AWS1?

Many thanks